# div selected problem

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have 4 div's set in following manner:
<1st div> <2nd div>
<3rd div> <4th div>
Whenever, mouse hover over any of the div, div background should be changed.

How can I achieve this. Use of jQuery is also allowed.
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried reading jquery manual at all? They cover basic things like this over there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using **jQuery**.

```
$('div').hover(function() {
   $(this).css({ backgroundImage: 'url(whatever.jpg)' });
}, function() {
   $(this).css({ backgroundImage: 'none' });
});
```

However, if I was doing this, I'd add a class and use CSS to change the actual background image.

You could do it with **plain JavaScript** too...

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');

for (var i = 0, divsLength = divs.length; i < divsLength; i++) {
    divs[i].onmouseover(function() {
            divs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(whatever.jpg)';
        });

    divs[i].onmouseout(function() {
            divs[i].style.backgroundImage = 'none';
        });
}
```

And you could even do it with **CSS** only...

```
div:hover {
    background-image: url(whatever.jpg);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with simple CSS pseudo-class `:hover`:

```
div:hover{
    background:url('your_background_path')}
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming those are the only 4 divs...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready( function() {
       $( 'div' ).mouseover( function() {
          $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'red' );
       });
       $( 'div' ).mouseout( function() {
          $( this ).css( 'background-color', 'white' );
       });
    });
</script>
```

If they are -not- the only 4 divs, you'll need to study up on jQuery selectors.  Maybe give the 4 divs a specific class name and reference that.

Comment: @naveen - added, thanks.  altho the :hover answers above are the better responses.  Hadn't thought of that :(

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#div1').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
        });
        $('#div2').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
        });
        $('#div3').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'blue');
        });
        $('#div4').mouseover(function () {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'aqua');
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need four different image on hover you can simply give four differnet class or id and here i used id.  css eg as

```
#firstdiv:hover{
background-image: url:('url');
}


#secondiv:hover{
    background-image: url:('url');
    }
```

and similarly remaining two.

Comment: Never heard of the CSS property `backgraoundimage` ? :P